# How to call specific Static Blocks inside product descriptions in Magento?

Tags: magento-1.7

I tried adding a static block to my product description by adding the following code to my description page:

`<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('description02')->toHtml() ?>`

This works.  But what can I do if I want to use different static blocks for different products? I don't want the same static block to show on all products. Is there way that I can choose which static block shows?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can proceed as follows :

Create a new text type product attribute from Catalog -> Attributes and add it in used Attribute set from Catalog -> Attribute sets

After this you can add different static block names into this field while adding/editing products.

On product details page use the same you are using above, just make the static block to fetch name from the above created attribute.

Hope this will help.

### UPDATE

Lets suppose you created a new attribute named "static_block" then go to Attribute sets, click on the set you are using for the product you want to show the block into.

Drag and drop the static_block from the unassigned to assigned attribute and save Attribute set.

After this create multiple static block block for ex : block_1, block_2

Edit product and in the field assigned above enter block_1 or block_2

After this on product description template i.e catalog/product/view.phtml add code as per following example :

```
<?php
$blockId = $_product->getData('static_block');
```

OR

```
$blockId = $_product->getStatic_block();
```

Whichever works

```
echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId($blockId)->toHtml() ?>
```

you may need to tweak in above code as i have not tested this.

Hope this helps.

Comment: thank you so much for your answer.  I was a bit confused as to how to implement this solution. I went to Catalog -> Attributes and created a new attribute called Static Text.  Then I went to Catalog -> Attribute set and created a new set named it Static Blocks and double clicked on the Unassinged attribute Static Text.  Now how do I call the static blogs from the product description? When I add the code above, it shows the actual code on the description.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  I tried it and I am able to add the attribute and attribute set without a problem.  I can also echo what's in that attribute on the product page.  However, when I write the static block's identifier, i.e: block_1, the output is "block_1" as opposed to what I have saved in the static block.  I tried using just the name "block_1" and {{block type="cms/block" block_id="your_block_id"}}

Answer (score 1):

1) Create Attribute caller for example **static_block_description_code**

2) Attach this attribute to proper Attributes Set in Admin section too (set, which You use for you're desired product)

3) go to (in my example) app/design/frontend/PACKAGE/default/template/catalog/product/view/**description.phtml** and search line responsible to display standard description
I have:`

```
<div class="std">
    <?php echo $this->helper('catalog/output')->productAttribute($this->getProduct(), $_description, 'description') ?>
</div>`
```

and i've changed it to `

```
<div class="std block-description">
    <?php echo $this->helper('catalog/output')->productAttribute($this->getProduct(), $_description, 'description') ?>
    <?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId($block_description)->toHtml() ?>
</div>`
```

On top of this file I've added:

```
<?php $_product = $this->getProduct(); ?>
<? 
    $block_description = $_product->getData('static_block_description_code');
?>
```

Comment: I understand long years back, same thing any help for magento 2, here the description cms block change based on attributes, https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/330082/57334 @moka